# FirebaseAuth with Google Sign failed to handle onActivityResult

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

when handling the return of sign google activity i have the following error:

> 02-13 23:53:33.729 14395-14395/br.com.easytrip E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                    Process: br.com.easytrip, PID: 14395
>                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=711, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {br.com.easytrip/br.com.easytrip.features.login.view.LoginGoogleActivity}: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 8: 
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4130)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4173)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1546)
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
>                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
>                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
>                                                                     Caused by: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 8: 
>                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzb.zzy(Unknown Source)
>                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(Unknown Source)
>                                                                        at br.com.easytrip.features.login.view.LoginGoogleActivity.onActivityResult(LoginGoogleActivity.kt:46)
>                                                                        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6946)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4126)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4173) 
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1546) 
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165) 
>                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
>                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)

My code snippet for onActivityResult:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_REQUEST) {
        data?.let {
            val signedInAccountFromIntent = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(intent)
            presenter.handleGoogleLogin(signedInAccountFromIntent)
        } ?: handleGoogleSignInError()
    } else {
        handleGoogleSignInError()
    }
}
```

My code snippet for google sign in Intent:

```
private fun setUp() {
    val googleSignInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()

    googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, googleSignInOptions)

    val account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)
    if (account != null && account.idToken != null) {
        account.idToken?.let{
            setResult(it)
        } ?: showGenericError()
    } else {
        val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_REQUEST)
    }
}
```

I have added a sha1 debug key in firebase console.

Comment: Are you using release version for your testing?

Comment: @RahulChandrabhan no, I am testing in debug version

Comment: Have you tested on phone or emulator, because I face problems whenever I use emulator for login purpose.

Comment: @RahulChandrabhan I using a phone for testing, even used in release version, very estrange issue